# Retrieve values of a mapping in an array

Tags: solidity

For example,

```
struct somestruct {
        uint someuint;
        mapping(address=>uint) somemapping;
    }


arrayofsomestruct[] public _arrayofsomestruct;
```

The getter function automatically created for `_arrayofsomestruct` seems to return `someuint` in the array, but not the mapping values? Is an additional getter function required to retrieve the values in `somemapping`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use a `getter` function where you retrieve all values about specific struct inside array.
See this smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract RetrieveMappingValuesFromStructArray {
    struct somestruct {
        uint someuint;
        mapping(address=>uint) somemapping;
    }

    somestruct[] public _arrayofsomestruct;

    function setStruct(uint _firstValue, address _address,  uint _secondValue) public {
        somestruct storage someStruct = _arrayofsomestruct.push();
        someStruct.someuint = _firstValue;
        someStruct.somemapping[_address] = _secondValue;
    }

    function getStruct(uint index, address _address) external view returns(uint someuint, uint somemapping) {
        return (_arrayofsomestruct[index].someuint, _arrayofsomestruct[index].somemapping[_address]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't expect such a detailed answer, thank you. BTW, without the getter function in this contract, can other contract get the mapping values of this contract through a getter function? If the array is accessible to the other contract.

Comment: You'll have ever to create a getter function in other contract to access into keys and values mapping.